# Workers on php freeze on Supervisor after 2 days of working

Tags: php, rabbitmq, supervisord, worker, php-amqplib

**Hi all!**

I write **workers** on **php** (Yii2) for processing rabbitMQ messages using [php-amqplib](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib).

**Code example:**

```
public function start($message)
{
    $this->_getChannel()->queue_declare($this->_getQueueName(), false, true, false, false);

    $this->stdout(" [*] Worker ". $this->_getQueueName() ." started\n", Console::BOLD);
    $this->_getChannel()->basic_qos(null, 1, null);

    $this->_getChannel()->basic_consume(
    $this->_getQueueName(), '', false, false, false, false, [$this, 'rabbitCallback']
    );

    while (count($this->_getChannel()->callbacks)) {
       $this->_getChannel()->wait();
    }

    $this->_getChannel()->close();
}

public function rabbitCallback($message)
{
    $this->callbackResponse(json_decode($message->body, true));

    $message->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($message->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
}
```

I use **supervisor** for demonize workers.

All works fine for first 2 days, then I see in RabbitMQ:

```
Ready 1000 msg
Unacked 1000 msg
```

Workers don't read messages at all, count increased.

```
supervisor> status
    journal:journal_00    RUNNING   pid 103516, uptime 3 days, 20:40:55
    journal:journal_01    RUNNING   pid 103517, uptime 3 days, 20:40:55
    journal:journal_02    RUNNING   pid 103514, uptime 3 days, 20:40:55
```

Supervisor tell that workers works fine, but messages can be read.

If I restart supervisor - all start working fine, messages start decrease.

Logs are clear =(

**Does anyone of you have a same problem?**